# Webpack and JQuery-Validation: How to load language files dynmacialy

Tags: jquery, webpack, localization

How can I load the language files dynamically with webpack?

```
import validate from 'jquery-validation'
import 'jquery-validation/dist/localization/messages_de'
import 'jquery-validation/dist/localization/methods_de'
```

I could do something like

```
let lang = 'de'
import('jquery-validation/dist/localization/messages_' +  lang)
```

But how is webpack resolving this? I guess I have to define somewhere all possible combinations?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far

```
var lang = "{{ set_current_lang_here }}";
switch(lang) {
      case 'de':
        import('jquery-validation/dist/localization/messages_de');
        break;
      case 'pl':
        import('jquery-validation/dist/localization/messages_pl');
        break;
      ....
    }
```

But it feels hacky, because I have to enter all languages by hand.